# Binding double property to AngleProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Is there a way to control rotation of rectangle via Binding ? I tried it this way but it does not work any idea ?

```
    // class Unit
    private double _rotation;
    public double rotation
    {
        get
        {
            return _rotation;
        }
        set
        {
            _rotation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("rotation");
        }
    }
    public Binding rotationBinding { get; set; }

    // Controller class generating UI
    private Rectangle GenerateUnit(Unit u)
    {

        Rectangle c = new Rectangle() { Width = u.size, Height = u.size };

        c.Fill = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\..\Images\tank\up.png", UriKind.Relative)));
        c.SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, u.xBinding);
        c.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, u.yBinding);

        RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(rt, RotateTransform.AngleProperty, u.rotationBinding);
        c.LayoutTransform = rt;

        return c;
    }
```

X and Y bindings work fine so I guess that is implemented correctly.

I am just looking for a way to bind the angle property so when I change the rotation property it will rotate the rectangle in UI. (I dont need animation, switching the angle instantly is fine).

Thanks

Comment: How do you create `rotationBinding`? You should post that code too.

Comment: Yes it was written wrong way... I am sorry for useless thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be in your rotationBinding. You should create binding in your `Unit` class:

```
rotationBinding = new Binding("rotation");
rotationBinding.Source = this;// or instance of o your Unit class if you create rotationBinding outside Unit class
```

It works for me...

Comment: Thanks a lot I guess I was a bit overworked. There was a mistake in rotationBinding

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against creating the binding in code when you can do it all through XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Slider x:Name="AngleProvider"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Minimum="0"
                Maximum="360" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue"
                   Margin="100"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Value, ElementName=AngleProvider}" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This shows a `Rectangle` element in the centre of the window, and a `Slider` control at the bottom. Drag the slider to change the rotation angle of the rectangle.

What you should bind to is the angle of rotation. Here I am using the slider to provide that angle, but it could obviously come from a property in the code-behind of the window or a ViewModel or whatever.